# Copy numbered files to corresponding numbered directory using Linux bash commands or script

Tags: linux, bash, copy

This should be a relatively straightforward problem but I haven't found any answers within stackoverflow. In a given directory, I have ~1000 files that are numbered (e.g. chem-0320.inp). I would like to cp the numbered file to a correspondingly numbered directory; all copied files will be renamed with the same name. I would like to do this for a specified numbered of files (#'s 300-500 for example).

For example, I would like to copy chem-0320.inp to a directory named 320 and rename it mech.dat. 
Another example: copy chem-0430.inp to a directory named 430 and rename it mech.dat.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The following script would do the work for you

```
for file in *.inp
do  
 dir=$(echo $file | sed -r 's/[^0-9]+0([0-9]+).*/\1/g')
 mv $file $dir/mech.dat 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I receive an error because the directory 0320 does not exit (directory 320 does exist). How do I truncate the name of the directory the files are copied to from 0xxx to xxx?

Comment: @user2461162 I have edited the answer so that it take cares if the direcotry doesnt exists

Comment: I may have been unclear in my response. I have directories numbered already so that for example directories numbered from 300-400 exist (not 0300-0400). I therefore do not need to create new directories, I just want to copy files to existing directories. How would you go about doing that?

Comment: @user2461162 sorry about that. I have corrected that in my answer. The files would now go to `320` and not to `0320`

Answer (score 0):

"cd" first to right dir. Subdirs will be created there.

```
#!/bin/bash

lo_limit=300
hi_limit=500

for file in ./*.inp
do
    dir="${file//[^0-9]/}"
    dir_cut="${dir:1:3}" # leading zero cut off
    if  [ $dir_cut -ge $lo_limit ] && [ $dir_cut -le $hi_limit ]; then
        echo "$file  $dir_cut"
        mkdir -p "$dir_cut"
        cp "$file" "$dir_cut"/mech.dat
    fi 
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have directories numbered already so that for example directories numbered from 300-400 exist (not 0300-0400). I therefore do not need to create new directories, I just want to copy files to existing ones. How would you go about adapting your code to do that (i.e. truncate the name of the $dir to the last three numbers (e.g. 320 not 0320))?

Comment: Also number limits are implemented like requested in the question.